# Javascript Tic Tac Toe Game : how to alert user that he won?

Tags: javascript, html, css, tic-tac-toe

I am learning Javascript and started a first game project : Tic Tac Toe game.

My project and it's code : **[Tic Tac Toe Project](https://repl.it/@CharlesLoumeau/TickTackToe-Game)**

I want to be able to show up a notification if user has won at the Tic Tac Toe game.

For now I just wanted to test my "winning" code by saying that you win if you put 3 X's on the first line :

**HTML :**

I inserted an empty paragraph with id which will be specifically used to show the notification

```
<p id="Notif" style="text-align : center"></p>
```

**JS :**

```
var Boxes = document.querySelectorAll("td")
Notif = document.getElementById("Notif")

  if (Boxes[0].textContent === "X" && Boxes[1].textContent === "X" && Boxes[2].textContent === "X") {
  console.log("Check Ok");
  Notif.textContent = "You won!"
}
```

It doesn't work and I think it must be about the execution order in the script? or maybe need a loop ?

When i load the page, put the 3 "X" in the first line, then launch in the console :

```
  if (Boxes[0].textContent === "X" && Boxes[1].textContent === "X" && Boxes[2].textContent === "X") {
  console.log("Check Ok");
```

I do get the log "Check Ok".

Comment: My guess is, that you should execute your "winning code" every time a new symbol is placed. Otherwise, your code will only get fired once when loading the page, when, of course, not enough Xs have been placed.

Answer (score 0):

You only seem to be running your check once. To ensure this is not the case, run the check every time the user sets an X, so that you re-check with every change.

To do this, use the corresponding event (`click` if the elements are clicked to set the X, or `keydown` if you're actually letting the user enter X's).

Comment: The first point is wrong `<script>` tag is in the end of the `<body>`

Comment: True, did not see the example project.

Answer (score 0):

That code is only called once. You need to wrap it inside a function and call it on every click on gameboard

```
function checkWin(){
  if (Boxes[0].textContent === "X" && Boxes[1].textContent === "X" && Boxes[2].textContent === "X") {
     console.log("Check Ok");
     Notification.textContent = "You won!"
  } 

}
function MarkBox() {
  if (this.textContent === "") {   // === means equal for true / false questions
    this.textContent = "X"  // = means change value of variable
  } else if (this.textContent === "X") {
    this.textContent = "O"
  }
  else { this.textContent = ""}
  checkWin();


}
```

See the working example [repl.it](https://repl.it/@MaheerAli/InconsequentialPungentProcedure)

Answer (score 0):

Its because you were just calling the condition only once when the script is loaded for the first time . so when you choose X or O the script doesn't run the check again. so you need a function to wrap the condition and call it every time when the user inputs and that triggers the condition in the function . i just forked and modified your code here is the working code .https://repl.it/@syntax_hacker0/TickTackToe-Game

PS: implement all working cases of winning in the condition .